# TextSearch.TextPath timing on DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a data template:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="44" Source="{Binding Path}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Its for a combobox.

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageItemTemplate}" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"/>
```

This works almost as intended. If I am on the combobox, and I hit the "K" button on my keyboard, it will seek to all content within the combobox where the `name` starts with "K".

Moving on from that, if I then immediately hit the "W" button on my keyboard, it will not seek to content within the combobox where the `name` starts with "W". What it does is seek to the content that starts with "KW".

However, if instead of immediately hitting the "W" button after the "K" button, I instead wait 2-3 seconds before hitting the "W", when I hit the "W" button, it will then seek to the content starting with "W", as if it dropped the search for K after a few seconds.

I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate this wait time. I want the previous search text dropped imemdiately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Looking at the source code for TextSearcher it appears the timeout is not configurable programmatically. Here is how the timeout value is calculated:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Time until the search engine resets.
    /// </summary>
    private TimeSpan TimeOut
    {
        get
        {
            // NOTE: NtUser does the following (file: windows/ntuser/kernel/sysmet.c)
            //     gpsi->dtLBSearch = dtTime * 4;            // dtLBSearch   =  4  * gdtDblClk
            //     gpsi->dtScroll = gpsi->dtLBSearch / 5;  // dtScroll     = 4/5 * gdtDblClk
            //
            // 4 * DoubleClickSpeed seems too slow for the search
            // So for now we'll do 2 * DoubleClickSpeed

            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(SafeNativeMethods.GetDoubleClickTime() * 2);
        }
    }
```

And you cannot reset the search algorithm either, because the corresponding properties that keep current search prefix are private to TextSearch class.